# Alamofire json swift 2.2

Tags: json, ios9, alamofire, swift2

I'm trying to take out some data of facebook place's names with Alamofire but i have no luck. 
This is what i've tried and i cant figure out how to make it work.

*xcode 7.3*
*swift2.2*

So the result of the graph api is this

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "category": "Local business",
         "category_list": [
            {
               "id": "272705352802676",
               "name": "Outdoors"
            },
            {
               "id": "115725465228008",
               "name": "Region"
            }
         ],
         "location": {
            "street": "Athens",
            "city": "Palai\u00f3n F\u00e1liron",
            "state": "",
            "country": "Greece",
            "zip": "17562",
            "latitude": 37.9284637008,
            "longitude": 23.6944070162
         },
         "name": "THE NAME OF THE PLACE",
         "id": "THE ID"
      }
```

and i want to go inside "data" and take only the name and the ID of the place which are the 2 last lines.

And this is my code!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

 Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://graph.facebook.com/search", parameters: ["q": "", "type": "place", "center": "37.928319,23.7036673", "distance": "10000", "access_token": "ACCESS-TOKEN", "expires_in": "5184000"])
    .responseJSON { response in
        if let JSON = response.result.value {
            print("JSON: \(JSON["data"]!["name"]!)")
        }
}
}
```

and i get this error

> *fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value*

Any idea why?

Comment: print("JSON: \(JSON)") would be a good start. You are force unwrapping both 'data' and 'name'. Either once can fail if say your JSON is anything different than what you expect. At any case, it is not recommended to force unwrap in such cases, better use a 'if let'. Could be an 'error-JSON' of some kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this was easy i guess and it didn't worth the question but this is the solution

```
 Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://graph.facebook.com/search", parameters: ["q": "", "type": "place", "center": "37.928319,23.7036673", "distance": "10000", "access_token": "475827182628380|6U-mk-1etGQHwrXRSMF4Ht2zOyc", "expires_in": "5184000"])
            .responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
                if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
                    let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)

                    if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["data"].arrayObject {
                        self.arrRes = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                    }
                    if self.arrRes.count > 0 {
                        self.kati.reloadData()
                    }
                }
        }
```

And at the cell

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("checkInCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    var dict = arrRes[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = dict["name"] as? String
    //cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dict["email"] as? String
    return cell
}
```

Just dont forget to use SwiftyJSON too!